# Setting papertype in Matplotlib produces a warning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a series of figures that I am turning into a booklet.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

mosaic = """
        BC
        AA
        AA
        """

pp = PdfPages('/path/to/test.pdf')

for i in range(10):
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), facecolor='white')
    ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic)
    
    ax = ax_dict['A']
    ax.set_facecolor('lightgrey')

    plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf', papertype='A4', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=.5)
    fig.clf()
    
pp.close()
```

I get the warning

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: savefig() got unexpected keyword
> argument "papertype" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will
> become an error two minor releases later   plt.savefig(pp,
> format='pdf', papertype='A4', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=.5)

But in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/api/figure_api.html?highlight=papertype), `papertype` is still a parameter. Am I using in the wrong context?

Matplotlib version 3.4.3

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. If correctly done, your figure should still be saved, and presumably in A4 format.

Comment: But the documentation seems a bit lacking: it doesn't mention papertype is deprecated, while it also mentions the argument is only available for postscript (pdf is arguably based on postscript, but is not directly postscript). This is even the case for the current documentation, version 3.5.2.